# lwjgl And jars, not running

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, lwjgl

i'm a little stuck. I'm doing a little game in java, it's my first time, and i'm using sprites. I finally made it blink jaja, it's not much, but hey! I'm starting. the thing is that i'm using Netbeans 7.3 Ide, and my code runs. There's no problem. The problem comes when i export it as a jar. I export it and i get no error whatsoever, and the jar is created, but, i double click it, and nothing happens. Like, at all. Noting. I run it in Netbeans, and it runs. Any help would be really apretiated. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble with this too, at first.

Three things you're going to need to make it work properly:

1) The MANIFEST.MF - This is something that people don't think about much. The below code, make sure it is in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside your .jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/lwjgl.jar lib/lwjgl_util.jar lib/jinput.jar
Main-Class: <whatever your main method is in>
```

2) Alongside your jar, in whatever folder it is in, make a folder called 'lib'. Inside it, put all of the lwjgl jars that you are using. If you are using anything more than lwjgl.jar, lwjgl_util.jar, and jinput.jar, add it to the Class-Path variable in your MENIFEST.MF. Also, inside the lib folder, make a folder called 'natives' and take all of the native LWJGL files and put them inside that folder. That will be important for Step 3.

3) Add the following line of code early in your main method

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lib/natives").getAbsolutePath());
```

This is a "secret switch" used to enable the native files. It's smart, and only uses the natives for the operating system that the code is being run on, so don't worry about having all of the native files in the same directory.

And there you go. Export your Jar again with all of these things and you should be able to just simply double-click on it and make it launch!

Comment: OHHH Dude nice!!!! I already fixed it, but this looks A LOT BETTER, definitely i'll give you an update of how it went.

Comment: Dude, i'm trying to do it as you says, but it's not working. i'm sure i messed up something with the librarys. I used a java app to make a Fat Jar, but, when i send the file to another pc, it's not running.

Comment: I can make it run here, on my pc, and now it's running, i was using JarSplice, and it runs in my pc. But in otheres, doesn't do anything. Any further help?

Comment: I made it run FINALLY! BUUUUUT it only works with 64bits Windows OS.

Comment: Haha more and more, noup, it only works on my pc, but not in others. I'm getting tired.

Comment: JAJAJAJA Found the error man! Jaja it's pretty stupid... It wasn't running... because i'm using png's as sprites... AND THEY AREN'T IN THE OTHER COMPUTERS! JAJAJA derp!. Ok i'm posting a question about how to get the pngs from a subsequent folder.